# Building an App in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I have a client that wanted an easier way for his team members to build/update pages on their site, their site is heavily customized with a lot of JavaScript. The issues is that when a team member wanted to add a new section to the page they had consult a dev person to hard code in the desired features. So we decided to create customizable web parts of those features making the site more self-serviceable.

When I first started I found some documentation that said to use visual studios to build the web part using sandbox code, upload it to the site and then they would just need to activate it to deploy it on the site. Buuut unbeknownst to me code based sandbox solutions are no longer supported in Sharepoint and therefore the web parts we built could not be deployed. I was then told that I needed to build it as an Add-in, but as I started building the add-ins I found that the customizable field properties (i.e. ability to change background color, text style/color and banner color) that I want are not implementable as a add-ins.

So now I’m back at square one and I don’t know if it’s even possible to build a web part as a add-in or do I need to go a different route?

Any thoughts or links to sources you can provide would be HUGELY appreciated!

Thanks
Terek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2016 things have changed a lot from the traditional model which was the classic way of building web parts. The way you worked before is called "classic", the new way is called "modern", and the way to get your dev environment is the following (brace yourself, it is a long answer):

1) In SP2016/Online you will need to configure your dev machine with the following environment, installing the following:

- NodeJS Long Term Support version
- Yeoman (which will be used to create web parts)
- GULP (which will play the role of virtual web server)

  Once the three components above are installed, you will install the Yeoman SharePoint Generator to create the SharePoint Web Parts, Yeoman simplifies the process of creating things by delivering templates ready to use and making all the configurations standard, you gonna love this guy!

  To configure your machine see the following link:
  https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

2) In SP2016/SP Online, you will develop for SPFx (SharePoint Framework), Microsoft has made significant efforts to address the changes and help developers to embark on this new journey by publishing training and educational material at GitHub, YouTube, and on its official website (I will add link below), but for the purpose of helping you, please follow this tutorial, it helped me to learn how to develop Modern Web Parts for SP 2016/Online:

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

3) From the tutorial above, you will get a fully functional Modern Web Part that can be deployed to SP2016/Online, you will see the new modern architecture allows you that old experience of "sandboxing" web parts in a faster way without, thus solving your problem of constant updating/refactoring components in a live production environment. This way now allows you to constantly update the code and see the results in real-time , you will be able to see results on your dev environment by calling:  https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html  and at same time on your SP environment. for example: http://portal.company.com/_layouts/workbench.aspx

Links:

YouTube "SharePoint Framework Tutorials" - it is the step by step tutorial video showing the whole process of creating a web part:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLR9nK3mnD-OXvSWvS2zglCzz4iplhVrKq

GitHub repository with the full documentation, samples and extras for the SPFx and PnP (this is another story for another time):

https://github.com/SharePoint

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot!